# Can't make a full backup from Disk Utility before upgrading because “Not enough space”

Tags: macos, backup

I'm trying to clone a 2 TB SSD to a 1 TB HDD as a backup, in case the macOS upgrade goes wrong.

I read that sometimes, Time Machine fails at restoring, so I'd rather do that the old fashion way, following that method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfJrAcnHN2g.
Basically, I want to make a plain backup of the SSD's content, which I can reload if necessary.

Problem: Even if my SSD is actually occupied with around 380 GB data, it's basically seen as 2 TB as if it was fully used, so that I'm not allowed to clone.

Any workaround?

Comment: Can you clarify - are you trying to clone from 2TB SSD to 1TB HDD ?

Comment: Also - what are you cloning with & what's wrong with Time Machine?

Comment: The SSD has a capacity of 2 TB, but is only used up to 20%.

I'm cloning because I need to upgrade to a newer version of MacOS.

Howver, I want to be sure to be able to backpedal in case something goes wrong.
Therefore, I want to backup the current state of the hard drive. I could use Time Machine, but I read somewhere that sometimes it just basically fuck it up, in which case... You're just screwed.
Cloning is an alternative (which I use to install the SSD, it worked great). The problem is that the whole drive is seen as 2 TB, even if it's not fully used.

Answer (score 0):

You can not 'clone' a drive image bigger than the destination drive. Copy files.

Comment: Afaik the OP wants to copy an image.